# react-native-vector-icons do not load on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

i have my react native app where i added material community icons, everything was good when i was running my app by **npm run ios -- --simulator="iPhone 15 Pro"**, but when i am running by **npx expo start** icons are showing question mark

to set up icons on ios i used this:https://medium.com/clarusway/setting-up-react-native-vector-icons-for-ios-a5d57e78cdb2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an expo app, then there is no need to go to Xcode and add the icons. The tutorial is for bare react native apps.

The correct way to setup vector icons in expo is by following the docs here:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/icons/

> This library is installed by default on the template project using npx create-expo-app and is part of the expo package. It is built on top of react-native-vector-icons and uses a similar API. It includes popular icon sets that you can browse at icons.expo.fyi.

Comment: i was following docs but i have the same problems(all icons are question marks)